# Namespace tags are not supported. ReactJSX is not XML

Tags: javascript, jsp, reactjs

I am getting the below react exception in the browser console, It seems that jsp tags are not supported in React, Could someone confirm ? In case they are supported, What would be the solution ?

Code :

```js
render: function() {
  
  var defaultComp=this.state.defaultComp;
  var defaultUI=[];
  for(var compIndex=0;compIndex<defaultComp.length;compIndex++){
   //Push label first 
   defaultUI.push(
    <form:label path={defaultComp[compIndex]['path']}>
     {defaultComp[compIndex]['label']}
    </form:label>
    );

   if(defaultComp[compIndex]['type']==='input'){
    defaultUI.push(
     <form:input path={defaultComp[compIndex]['path']} />
    );
   }else{


   }

   defaultUI.push(<br/>);
  }
   return ( 
     <div id="section">
      <form:form action="display-makes.html" 
       method="post" commandName="configuration">
       {defaultUI}
      </form:form> 
     </div>
    );
  }
```

```
browser.min.js:7 Uncaught SyntaxError: http://localhost:8080/Neo/resources/js/script.jsx: Line 48: Namespace tags are not supported. ReactJSX is not XML.
      46 |          //Push label first 
      47 |          defaultUI.push(
    > 48 |              <form:label path={defaultComp[compIndex]['path']}>
         |      ^
      49 |                  {defaultComp[compIndex]['label']}
      50 |              </form:label>
      51 |              );
```

Comment: Why would JSP tags, which are serverside, work in a clientside library?

Comment: Sorry! But I did not get your question. Server side is Spring

Comment: JSP is rendered on the server and then plain HTML is sent to the browser. React is rendered in the browser. Your JSP tags will not work. To put it more plain; React does not support JSP tags. Nor does it support namespaces.

Comment: Got it. So I have to replace jsp tags with html tags

Comment: html tags or React components